# query is not returning distinct record

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, distinct

Hi can you please take a look why my query is not returning distinct record. i want result with following condition `OE1='SCHEDCHNG'`, need only recent records per orderid or ordernum means only one record per ordernum or orderid and also dropdate is null. My query is as below

```
    select DISTINCT TOP 100 OE.ORDERID,OE.ID,OE.ORDERNUM,OE.OE4  from OrderExports OE
inner join (
    select ORDERNUM, max(OE4) as MaxDate
    from OrderExports
    group by ORDERNUM
) tm
 on OE.ORDERNUM = tm.ORDERNUM and OE.OE4 = tm.MaxDate
 inner join orde_ O on OE.ORDERID = O.ORDERID 
 WHERE OE1='SCHEDCHNG' AND O.DROPDATE is null
```

[image: query result with duplicate record]

Comment: `DISTINCT` excludes identical rows, all the rows in your picture are different.

Comment: @JaydipJ sorry i miss that but this will not effect on result set i think

Comment: These are distinct records.  For example, 1870616 has two distinct IDs

Comment: @AlexK. yes so i m not getting correct result , but how can i do that please advice me

Comment: @JohnCappelletti we can distinct on ORDERNUM with all result there is not any problem if i will not display orderid

Comment: How can we advise you here? We don't have any idea what you are trying to do. Do you want only the most recent row? If so, what defines the group that you are looking for?

Comment: @SeanLange i want to re write this statement for OE1='SCHEDCHNG', need only recent records per orderid or ordernum means only one record per ordernum or orderid and also dropdate is null only this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sparse on details here but I think you are wanting something along these lines.

```
with SortedResults as
(
    select OE.ORDERID
        , OE.ID
        , OE.ORDERNUM
        , OE.OE4  
        , ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by OE.ORDERID, OE.ORDERNUM order by OE.OE4 desc) as RowNum
    from OrderExports OE
    inner join 
    (
        select ORDERNUM
            , max(OE4) as MaxDate
        from OrderExports
        group by ORDERNUM
    ) tm on OE.ORDERNUM = tm.ORDERNUM and OE.OE4 = tm.MaxDate
     inner join orde_ O on OE.ORDERID = O.ORDERID 
     WHERE OE1='SCHEDCHNG' 
        AND O.DROPDATE is null 
)

select ORDERID
    , ID
    , ORDERNUM
    , OE4
from SortedResults
where RowNum = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using max and group by as below :

```
SELECT a.ID, max(a.ORDERID) as OrderID, max(a.ORDERNUM) as OrderNum,MAX(OE.OE4) as OE4 FROM
(
--your query
 ) a
 group by a.ID
```